# HTTP request to return a list of Contacts

Tags: contact, httprequest, httpresponse

I would like to change the following method within this class:

```
public class ApexCalloutsDemo {

    public static HttpResponse makeCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            List<Object> contacts = (List<Object>) results.get('contacts');
            System.debug('Received the following contacts:');
            for (Object contact: contacts) {
                System.debug(contact);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Into a method that returns a list of Contacts:

```
public static List <Contact> getContact () {
list <Contact> contacts = new list <Contacts>();

...http request here

return contacts;
}
```

How am I doing this? I want to display the Contacts in the component as the view part of the mvc model. Therefore I need to return a list of contacts, not the http response and not a list of objects. When I do the following I get the error "Incompatible types since an instance of Contact is never an instance of List".

```
public class ContactsAndWebServiceController {

    //@AuraEnabled
    /**public static List <Contact> fetchContacts() {
        List<Contact> contList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Email, MailingCity from Contact LIMIT 10];
        return contList;
    }**/

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List <Contact> fetchContacts() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        List<Contact> contactsList = new list <Contact>();

        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
            Map<String, Contact> results = (Map<String, Contact>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            // Cast the values in the 'contacts' key as a list
            List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>) results.get('contacts');
            System.debug('Received the following contacts:');
            for (Contact contact: contacts) {
                contactsList.add(contact);
            }
        }
        return contactsList;
    }  
}
```

The JSON is the endpoint of a Salesforce community example. Here is an exzerpt:

{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },

Comment: good questions on SFSE should have 3 components: what are you trying to achieve, what you have tried so far and what problem do you face.  First two components you provided, what about the third one?

Comment: What is the actual JSON content? Is it deserializable to a `Contact` instance or no?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? You want to change the return type of your current method from `HttpResponse` to `List<Contacts>`? If yes, that will be simply to return the `contacts` you already have, are you not able to do so? What issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to display the Contacts in the component as the view part of the mvc model. Therefore I need to return a list of contacts, not the http response and not a list of objects.

Comment: It should be a simple transformation but it did not work for me as I am unexperienced with this topic...

Comment: When you say it did not work for you, what issues you got? What did you try? Providing those information here will help you to get more responses. In its current form, you seem to be asking someone to refactor the method for you, which may not get you enough response on your question.

Comment: Hi I just modified my question and stated what I tried so far...

Comment: @user40501 could you provide an example of JSON as well?

Comment: You can view the JSON in the endpoint link, it is an example from the Salesforce community. But I also post it in the code.

Comment: Anyona help please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you are receiving doesn't represent Salesforce Contacts as such, just data *about* contacts. Because the data is structured in a way that doesn't map 1:1 to the Salesforce data model, you will have to actually write code to convert the data into Contact records. For example, you would need to, for each incoming record,

- Split the `name` property into a `FirstName` and `LastName` (at least).
- Split the `address` property into the components of an `Address` compound field.
- Extract the three phone numbers from their sub-object and map them to appropriate `Contact` fields.

It's not particularly complex code, but it's not trivial either and you need to think through how exactly you want to handle incoming data - especially if it is formatted badly.

However, you mentioned in the comments

> I want to display the Contacts in the component as the view part of the mvc model. Therefore I need to return a list of contacts, not the http response and not a list of objects

This is not strictly accurate. You can display, in both Visualforce and Lightning, data that is not structured as sObjects or queried from the database. You won't be able to *persist* those records to the database without building actual sObjects out of them, but using techniques like wrapper classes that represent data in Apex structures for display and user interaction is very common. That *would* be a "list of objects", either a `List<SomeCustomObject>` or perhaps a `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

If you search SFSE for "wrapper class", you'll find lots of examples. (I also previously wrote about this approach in a [blog post](https://www.ktema.org/2018/02/17/everyday-salesforce-patterns-wrapper-class/)).

Comment: Hi David, it happens now that I need to process the data, like split name and address, and extract the three phone numbers from their sub-object. Could you please help me here how I do this? Do i manipulate the JSON string, because it seems I cannot do a get(property) on the object as it is not an sObject...